# Install react-native app on android

Tags: android, react-native, create-react-native-app

How can I install react-native app on my android device locally, without publishing anything to Play Store. The app was created with `create-react-native-app` command?

Answer (score 0):

For installing your app locally on mobile, follow these steps

> 1. Enable developer mode in mobile.For android refer [here](https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-get-developer-options-on-android/)
> 2. Connect your android phone to your system.
> 3. Follow these steps in CMD to enable platform-tools. Note: path may differ
>     **cd
>      C:\Users\YourFolderName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
>
>      adb devices
>     adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081**
>
> 4.Once your run `adb devices` you can see your device in the list.
>
> 5.run your app in CMD anf App will get installed in your Mobile and check it out.

Let me know does it worked

Comment: It didn't work, I assume there are some steps after this that should be done?

Comment: After the 4th step, did it shows you device's list ? And don't forget to run the command to start the app in CMD in 5th step

Answer (score -1):

use

```
npm run android
```

For more information, see this:-

https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app#npm-run-android

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question was How can I install the react-native app on my android device locally